# Create a custom error message with apex

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, adderror

I am trying to create an error message with apex when saving a quote.

I already have the logic done but I would like to know if I can create this type of error messages as shown in the image.

[image]

[image]

I don't know if it is a class that makes this type of messages.

Any recommendation is welcome.
Greetings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `addError` method on sobject which is in the trigger context. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm)

---

Example, how to add error on the sobject level

```
for(SObject sobj :Trigger.new){
    Account acct = (Account) sobj;
    if(acct.Name == 'Test'){
        acct.addError('This is not applicable record name.');
    }
}
```

---

Example, how to add error on the sobject field level

```
for(SObject sobj :Trigger.new){
    Account acct = (Account) sobj;
    if(acct.Name == 'Test'){
        acct.addError('Name', 'This is not applicable record name.');
    }
}
```

or

```
for(SObject sobj :Trigger.new){
    Account acct = (Account) sobj;
    if(acct.Name == 'Test'){
        acct.Name.addError('This is not applicable record name.');
    }
}
```